# virt-manager Windows guest access Linux host folder

Tags: linux, windows, shared-folders, virt-manager

I have the following configuration:

- Linux host: MX Linux 21 (based on Debian 11)
- Windows guest: Windows 8.1
- virt-manager: 3.2.0

I've created a shared folder in Linux labeled `L_data`.

Windows has built in Samba, and according to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86071/use-virt-manager-to-share-files-between-linux-host-and-windows-guest), I just need to find out which IP address the Linux host has (by using `ifconfig`) and map a drive to this ip. When I issued the `ifconfig` command, it showed 4 interfaces: `eth0`, `eth1`, `lo`, `virbr0`.

From the Windows guest, I could ping the IP of the host, but when I tried to map the drive, it won't see the host. What I'm missing?

Questions:

1. which of those 4 interfaces am I supposed to use? I used the IP of `eth0` (only `eth1` has no IP)
2. my IP is dynamic, if it changes, how to make sure the Windows guest can still see the host folder?

PS: I'm not that knowledgeable about Linux.

Comment: The correct Linux IP address to consider should be the one provided *by* Linux to be a gateway for Windows: the IP address on `virbr0`. It's probably *not* dynamic, and would probably be 192.168.122.1 with default settings.

Comment: Also it's not very clear when you write "Windows has built in Samba". Samba is the server side. So you can configure Windows to be server for Linux and use mount.cifs on Linux. But if you want Windows as **client** then Linux must have Samba, not Windows.

Comment: @A.B, thanks for your feedback, I have Samba already installed on Linux (Version 4.13.13-Debian), and thanks for the tips, I could see the folder in Linux.

Comment: Please post an answer explaining how you solved the problem. That lets other people benefit from the time and energy everyone invested

Comment: May I ask why you aren't using Virtual Box?

Answer (score 1):

I won't say this is the answer, but it solved my sharing problem.

- Linux > Thunar > select folder to share on the right panel > right click > Properties > Share tab > check Share this folder & Allow other users to write in this folder > enter name in Share name (L_data) > click Apply & OK.
- $ifconfig in command line
- virbr0: is the Linux ip address bound to Windows > write down this ip and in Windows guest, go to map drive and enter this ip address.